# How to export with codefolding in jupyter?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to export jupyter notebook to html, with the codefolding extension enabled.

I've tried to follow [the official docs](http://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nbextensions/codefolding/readme.html)

I've tried the following lines in `~/.jupyter/jupyter_nbconvert_config.py`

```
# # not working, tried one line at a time
# Exporter.preprocessors += ['jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.CodeFoldingPreprocessor']
# Exporter.preprocessors += ['jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.pre_codefolding']
# c.Exporter.preprocessors.append('jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.pre_codefolding')

# working for cmd line, eg:
# jupyter nbconvert --to html my_nb.ipynbc.Exporter.preprocessors.append('jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.CodeFoldingPreprocessor')
c.Exporter.preprocessors += ['jupyter_contrib_nbextensions.nbconvert_support.CodeFoldingPreprocessor']
c.CodeFoldingPreprocessor.remove_folded_code=True
```

None of the above works in jupyter notebook `File` -> `Download as` -> `HTML (.html)`

However, `jupyter nbconvert --to html my_nb.ipynb` in command line does work.

**Q: How can I make this work in jupyter notebook?**

FYI, I'm running:

- jupyter_client 5.1.0
- jupyter_core 4.3.0
- Python 3.6.2

Comment: Getting a feeling that it's a bug in the notebook

Comment: Now I'm using: `docker exec jupyter jupyter nbconvert --to html --CodeFoldingPreprocessor.remove_folded_code=True /home/jovyan/work/notebooks/test.ipynb`